# Theorem $9.28$ Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

I have some questions about theorem $9.28$ (Implicit Function Theorem) in Baby Rudin, here's a related question.
[Doubt in the proof of Implicit function theorem by Rudin's PMA,(Theorem 9.28,p224-227)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844890/doubt-in-the-proof-of-implicit-function-theorem-by-rudins-pma-theorem-9-28-p22)

I still don't understand the first question in the related one.

> 1.Let $f$ be a ′− mapping of an open set $E \in R^{n+m}$ to $R^{n}$. Let $\textbf{F}(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y})=(\textbf{f}((\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}) , \textbf{y}) ,\space ;(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y})\in E$. Then how can we prove that  is a ′− mapping of  into $R^{n+m}$?

The comment said we should use the chain rule but I still don't get it

Comment: Is your $C'$ in reality a $C^1$, the space of continuously differentiable functions? A primed space usually denotes the dual space, the space of bounded linear functionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information, we get into a bit of trouble with the domain and codomain of these functions, and I think that you and the linked question have some typos.  That being said, if we take $E = \Bbb R^{n + m}$ we can say the following:

The functions $f:\Bbb R^{n + m} \to \Bbb R^n$ and $G:\Bbb R^{n+m} \to \Bbb R^{n+m}$ defined $G(x,y) = (f(x,y),y)$ are both $C^1$.  It follows that the function $F = f \circ G$ is $C^1$ by the chain rule.  That is, the function
$$
F(x,y) = f(f(x,y),y)
$$
is countinuously differentiable.

If we take the domain of $f$ to be $E$, then $f(f(x,y),y)$ will only be defined if $(f(x,y),y) \in E$.

---

To show that $G$ is $C^1$, it suffices to note that for functions $f_1$ over $\Bbb R^k$ and $f_2$ over $\Bbb R^k$, the function $x \mapsto (f_1(x),f_2(x))$ is $C^1$ if and only if both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are $C^1$.

This in turn is a consequence of the following: for $f_1,\dots,f_n$ defined over $\Bbb R$, the function $x \mapsto (f_1(x),\dots, f_n(x))$ is $C^1$ if and only if each of $f_1,\dots,f_n$ is $C^1$.  Moreover, we have
$$
D_x (f_1(x),\dots, f_n(x)) = (D_xf_1, \dots, D_x f_n(x)).
$$

Comment: $F(x,y)$ in the book is the $G(x,y)$ you defined, we already know $f$ is $C^{1}$ and I am confused about why $G$ is $C^{1}$

Comment: It is unclear where you get the double application of $f$ in the first part from, there is nothing of it in the question and it makes no sense in the context of the IFT as underlying topic.

Comment: @Lutz I was very thrown off by the extra parenthesis